# PHP die throwing different error message than I want it to

Tags: php, javascript, error-handling

I have a Javascript function which calls a PHP script on my server. In case of failures, the JS function is expecting to receive a message of `save_failed` from the script.

For testing purposes, I put the wrong database info in the line below so that it fails:

```
mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "pass") or die('save_failed');
```

However, the JS function was not behaving as expected, and it seemed it wasn't receiving `save_failed` as the output. To confirm, I displayed the message being received as an alert box and this is what I got.

Why is the php script not throwing just `save_failed` and how can I make it do that?

[image: JS function received msg]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Xdebug installed and further errors are occurring.

In production, you should have [`error_reporting(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`ini_set('display_errors', '0')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).